# Как получить значения из checkboxlist в yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, checkbox

Хочу сделать вывод списка чекбоксов `$options`, с отмеченными уже полями `$selectors`:

```
$options = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($requirements, 'id', 'name_filter');
$event->m_requirement = $selectors;

$form->field($event, 'm_requirement')->checkboxList($options);
```

Это всё работает.

По идее, как я понимаю результат может быть доступен в контроллере, как `$event->m_requirement`. Но данное значение пусто.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего не прописаны правила валидации в `rules`.

Во `view`:

```
<?php
    $requirements = \frontend\models\Requirements::find()->all(); //Лучше во view так не делать :)
    $options = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($requirements, 'id', 'name');

    echo $form->field($model, 'requirements')->checkboxList($options);
?>
```

В контроллере делаем `load`:

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
```

И в модели получаем данные:

```
/**
 * Load отработает только для тех полей для которых прописаны правила валидации.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['requirements', 'safe']
    ];
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getRequirements()
{
    return $this->requirements;
}

/**
 * @param array $requirements
 */
public function setRequirements($requirements)
{
    /**
     * Здесь в приватном свойстве requirements после load будет хранится массив
     */
    $this->requirements = $requirements;
}
```